# Am I using the correct data types on SQL Server side to call an Oracle 10g function?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-10g

When calling an Oracle function with the following in parameter types

```
NUMBER(7,0)
VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)
DATE
```

and return type `NUMBER(14,5)` from SQL Server 2008R2 via a linked Oracle server, I declared the parameter variables on SQL Server side as follows:

```
numeric(7,0) -- also tried INT, BIGINT
varchar(8)
varchar(4)
datetime -- also tried DATE
```

and return variable type `numeric(14,5)`

```
exec ( 'BEGIN ? := db.pkg.getPrice(?,?,?,?); END;', @price, @id1, @id2, @curr, @ed ) AT ORASRV
```

The call fails with the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORASRV" returned message "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 1".
```

What am I doing wrong?

To test that function I used the following PL/SQL script and it worked fine (printed `0` which is a correct result for the parameters):

```
declare
  c varchar2(4);
  ed date;
  res number(14,5);
begin
  c := 'USD';
  ed := to_date('22-MAY-14', 'DD-Mon-YYYY');
  res := pkg.getPrice(214360, '129746', c, ed);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
end;
```

Also created a function just for testing:

```
create or replace FUNCTION getTest ( 
    a IN VARCHAR2 -- also tried INTEGER
)
RETURN  VARCHAR2 -- also tried INTEGER
IS
  res VARCHAR2(1); -- also tried INTEGER
BEGIN
  res := a;
  RETURN res;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN NULL;    
END;
```

When I call it from SQL Server as follows

```
declare @a varchar(1),@b varchar(1) -- also tried INT
select @b = 'a'
exec ( 'BEGIN ? := db.getTest(?); END;', @a, @b) AT ORASRV
```

I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORASRV" returned message "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1".
Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 172
Could not execute statement on remote server 'ORASRV'.
```

In case of INTEGER on Oracle side and INT on SQL Server side the message is just `"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`

Comment: How are you calling the function from the SQL Server side?

Comment: @MickyT As in the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datatypes should be okay, however you need to change your call slightly and add OUTPUT after your @price.  I've tested this against Oracle11g on INTEGER -> INT, VARCHAR2 -> VARCHAR, DATE -> Datetime using your getTest function

```
exec ( 'BEGIN ? := db.pkg.getPrice(?,?,?,?); END;', @price OUTPUT, @id1, @id2, @curr, @ed ) AT ORASRV
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm.